# Back button doesn't appear in navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, segue, back-button

I'm having trouble understanding the way view controllers are presented and how to navigate between them in swift. I have a contact list, when you click on one contact it opens the related conversation, but it doesn't show any back button to the conversation list. My storyboard is : 
Contact List -> Navigation Controller -> Messages Controller

There is no navigation controller before contact list because it messes up with a sliding menu.

Here is my code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "ShowConversationFromSelectedContact" {

        let nav = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
        let cdtvc = nav.topViewController as! MessageViewController
        cdtvc.currentConversation = openConversation

    }

}
```

More generally if you could explain or have any good ressource about the way stack of controllers work and how to navigate between them it would be great, I read a bunch articles but it's still unclear.

Comment: do you use storyBoard or is everything dynamically generated?

Comment: you can try this: `navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated:true)`

Comment: check out my answer, I'm 99% sure it is the solution

Answer (score 2):

Re-arrange it so it is `Nav Controller -> Contact list -> Message controller`, and use `push` segues (if you're using swift 1.2+, they're called `Show` segues).

Inside `prepareForSegue:` you don't need to do anything else besides setting the contact id (or whatever data you need to pass) to the message controller.

**Edit:**

For a sliding menu, I suggest the following navigation model:

1. The Storyboard `ViewController`s hierarchy goes

   `Nav Controller --root segue--> Contact List VC --show segue--> Message VC`
2. Sliding menus are usually to present **Top Level Views**. Your `Contact List VC` is a top level view. Since it is also the root VC, you can use `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` to assign a button to show your sliding menu.

Comment: Well as I said the problem is I cannot put the nav controller before contact list or it's breaking the way my sliding menu is displayed. Any other way?

Comment: The problem you have is that you're not pushing message controller to the stack, so you cannot "go back".. because there is no "back" to go to. Your message controller is the root viewcontroller. Because of this I **strongly** suggest that you redesign your sliding menu.

Comment: Another solution would be you present view controllers and dismiss them programatically, but that will 100% guaranteed give unnecessary headache.

Comment: And how can I present them programmatically in this case? I went for this solution because I couldn't figure out how to do my sliding menu inside a navigation controller, still very much a beginner here^^

Comment: checkout my edit on how to do this on a navigation controller